# How to get the status of completed item which opened in last two weeks

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I couldn't find question similar to mine so here is the thing.
I have query which gives me all the item opened and updated during the last two weeks.
I want to make it more useful by getting the status of all the opened items during the last two weeks and closed.
I don't care about other closed items which opened earlier.

Until now, I couldn't get the appropriate results to my query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the tickets that were opened within the last two weeks:

```
createdDate > -2w
```

now to filter only those that are closed extend the query to:

```
createdDate > -2w and resolution is not EMPTY
```

To find the statuses simply use the list view instead of detailed view and include the Status column (should be visible by default).